# TempData persisting after read in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, tempdata

In ASP.NET MVC 2, `TempData` values persist until the session ends or until they are read.  In the [words of Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx)...

> The value of TempData persists until
>   it is read or until the session times
>   out. Persisting TempData in this way
>   enables scenarios such as redirection,
>   because the values in TempData are
>   available beyond a single request.

I thought I understood this but I just came across unusual behavior in my application where a `TempData` value was available and it should not have been available.  In general, I have a controller with a series of actions where the first action sets a `TempData` value, the next few actions read and then set that `TempData` value, and the final action reads the TempData value.  Pseudo code below...

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1()
{
  TempData["bar"] = foo;
  return RedirectToAction("Step2");
}

public ActionResult Step2()
{
  var foo = TempData["bar"];
  TempData["bar"] = foo;
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step2()
{
  var foo = TempData["bar"];
  TempData["bar"] = foo;
  return RedirectToAction("Step3");
}

public ActionResult Step3()
{
  var foo = TempData["bar"];
  TempData["bar"] = foo;
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step3()
{
  var foo = TempData["bar"];
  return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction", "AnotherController");
}
```

My belief was that after reading a value, it would no longer be available in TempData.  But I started stepping through the code and while the key/value would be added to TempData on assignment, it would *never* go away when I pulled the value from TempData (even when I arrived in a different controller).

The only way I am able to get it to go away is to manually hit an action that reads from `TempData`.

Can anyone provide any pointers to help me better understand what is going on with `TempData` persistence in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to throw this out there...

RedirectToAction has a return type of RedirectToRouteResult.  This is called by several of the action methods in the above pseudo code.

According to this [possibly outdated blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/jacqueseloff/archive/2009/11/17/tempdata-improvements.aspx)...

> 4.RedirectResult and RedirectToRouteResult always calls
>   TempData.Keep()

and

> Calling Keep() from within an action
>   method ensures that none of the items
>   in TempData are removed at the end of
>   the current request, even if they were
>   read. The second overload can be used
>   to retain specific items in TempData.

So it looks like my TempData values are being automatically flagged.  I verified this by seeing these values show up under _initialKeys within TempData.