# MVC Action to be called only via RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want a MVC Action(say DoStuff()) to be called only via RedirectToAction method from another action.

I want to restrict calling this action "DoStuff" from browser urls.

I tried **ChildActionOnly** and **NonAction**.

But both failed. How do i achieve this?

Comment: You cannot reliably restrict this.  It's patently impossible.  You can use the url referrer field, but this is easily spoofed by anyone that knows what they're doing.  This is why it's not reliable.

Comment: If your action which is invoking the RedirectToAction resides within the same controller you can declare your action that you want to be restricted as private. That way methods/actions within this controller can invoke it but the action won't be accessible outside of that particular controller. If you are referencing it from other controllers then it can't be done as @ErikFunkenbusch points out...

Comment: @Marko - No, RedirectToAction results in a redirect, which is a new request, which comes from the client.  It won't be accessible if it's private

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Hmmm I guess you are correct I just tried it and I was unable to redirect to a private action from another action inside the same controller...

Comment: However I am able to return a call to a private ActionResult which then can return whatever view you want. It's not a redirect but it does allow you to create an action which is not accessible to the outside world and kind of serves the same idea with a redirect. Not sure what his scenario is but it might be useful to him...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only allow access to action if redirected from specific action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864366/only-allow-access-to-action-if-redirected-from-specific-action)